# @Postmapping is not working with axios.post

Tags: reactjs, spring, authentication, spring-mvc, axios

I am new to spring boot. Here the data is not coming from the react to spring.

```js
const details = JSON.stringify({ user: "admin", pass: "12345" });
console.log(details);
axios
  .post("/api/v1/login", {
    data: details,
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json;",
    },
  })
  .then((res) => console.log("done"));
```

This is post from react.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/login", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
             produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Login createEmployeeLogin(@RequestBody Login login) {
    System.out.println(login);
    System.out.println("test");
    return null;
}
```

The output is:

```
Login{user='null', pass='null'}
test
```

I have tried to get the data from react to spring, but its not working. I think the values are not coming to backend.

Comment: Is the frontend post request succesful though?

Comment: Add your `Login` class, what are you sending (what does `console.log` looks like.

Comment: Quick guess tells me you have no setters, or an All Args Constructor on your Login Pojo.

Comment: also, you have /api/v1/.  does your controller have this path as well?

Comment: {"user":"admin","pass":"12345"}  this is console.log      and the login class is public class Login{

    private String user;
    private String pass;     //getters and setters and tostring method

Comment: @JCompetence yes that path is available

Comment: @DamianBusz yes, i am getting the output which is available in that method and also getmappng is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])` correctly.

As shown in the [axios doc](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example), the second parameter is the json body (also it's not required to serialize the object yourself), and the third parameter takes the [request config](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) which includes the headers:

```js
const details = { user: "admin", pass: "12345" };
axios
    .post("http://localhost:8080/login", details, 
    {
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json;",
        }
    },
    )
    .then((res) => console.log("done"));
```

Your origin code will produce a Json body nested with the `data` and `headers` fields which is not what you want.